# Modify ProgressBars in a ListView individually

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar

I have a `ListView` that contains a `TextView` and a `ProgressBar` per item, filled using a custom `Adapter` like such:

```
String[] actions = new String[] {
        "Stretch", "Walk",
        "Drink water", "Eat fruit(s)" };

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    final RoutineArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = 
            new RoutineArrayAdapter(getActivity(), actions);
    setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);     
}

public class RoutineArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public RoutineArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, -1, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.routine_list_layout, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.action);
        textView.setText(values[position]);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

But each `ProgressBar` will be different depending on the text associated to it.

How may I modify each `ProgressBar` individually (size, color, progress value etc.) and programmatically?

Comment: You need to design your own data class and put it in a ArrayList, then pass it to the ArrayAdapter. Whenever you change any data, you call adapter.notifyDataSetChange() which will update the ListView. I have a blog about ListView: 
programandroidlistview.blogspot.com, it may help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) rowView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
```

You can get this progressBar inside getView(..) as the same that you accessed textview

Comment: But won't this set the changes to all progress bars in the list? Can I access them whenever I want and individually? Nevermind, I can probably use the position parameter :). I will accept your answer whenever I can.

Comment: Is there a way to update the progress bars individually out of the Adapter? Per example if a user clicks on one of them, it sets its value +1.

Comment: getView(..) method is called for every row in listview. If you set visibility like probgressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) if position=0, then only first progressbar will be displayed